# Creating a 2D array class: How to access element in a 2D array class like array[x][y]

Tags: c++

If I want my own 1D array class I can overwrite operator[] to read/write the elements. Like:

```
class A1D {
private:
  int a[10];  // This is irrelevant - it's just to simplify the example
              // The real class doesn't use a int array.
              // Here I just use an int array for simplicity

public:
  int& operator[] (int x) {  // <--- The interesting part...
    return a[x];
  }
};

int main()
{
  A1D a1d;
  a1d[5] = 42;
  std::cout << a1d[5] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The above works fine.

But what if I want to do the same for a 2D array class.

```
class A2D {
private:
  int a[10][10]; // This is irrelevant - it's just to simplify the example
public:
  int& operator[][] (int x, int y) {  // This, of cause, doesn't work
    return a[x][y];
  }
};
```

How would I code `[][]` to access elements in the 2D array class?

**EDIT - some clarification as the first answers didn't fully do what I needed**

I used `int` in the example above for simplicity. In the final class I won't use `int` so I can't return a `int*` and the rely on `(*int)[..]` for the second level.

So I'm looking for:

```
A2D a;
a[3][4] = SomeOtherClass;   // Should call function in A2D with arg 3 and 4
SomeOtherClass x = a[3][4]; // Should call function in A2D with arg 3 and 4
```

Comment: Use the first `[]` to return a pointer to a row.

Comment: A 2d array is often called a *matrix*.  Your answer can be found by searching the internet for "c++ faq matrix operator"

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I tried that but didn't find the answer. Do you have a link?

Comment: You can try these: [Operator Overloading](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading), look for the words "Matix"; [How do I create a subscript operator for a matrix](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html) - The point here is to use `operator()` instead of `[][]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a proxy class which will contain a pointer to the corresponding row of the matrix. Unlike the "return the pointer" approach explained in the other answer, this one can be as well applied to 3D and multidimensional matrices.

```
class RowProxy {
private:
    int* row;

public:
    explicit RowProxy(int* row) : row(row) {}
    int& operator[](int y) {
        return row[y];
    }
};

class A2D {
private:
  int a[10][10]; // This is irrelevant - it's just to simplify the example
public:
  RowProxy operator[](int x) {
      return RowProxy{a[x]};
  }
};
```

Comment: This is the road I prefer to implement it

Answer (score 2):

You can return a pointer to an array, for example:

```
class A2D {
private:
  int a[10][10]; 
public:
  int* operator[] (int x) {  
    return a[x];
  }
};
```

I don't like this solution... I think it's best to have a `Row` and a `Col` class and return an object, not a raw pointer.

You can also use `operator()()` instead of the bracket as an alternative

```
class A2D {
private:
  int a[10][10]; 
public:
  int& operator()(int x, int y) {  
    return a[x][y];
  }
};

A2D arr;
// ...
arr(3, 3) = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the first solution is not what I'm looking for as my code is only called for the first `[..]`

Comment: Your second example is what I'm looking for... except for the syntax. Instead of `arr(3, 3) = 5` I'm looking for `arr[3][3] = 5`. Any ideas?

Comment: @4386427 C++ does not provide a direct way to override [][] operator without proxy classes.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov So you are saying that it's impossible to do what I'm trying - right?

Comment: @4386427 No, I'm saying that it is possible but you need proxy classes like in my answers. Those proxies can do whatever you want, even call any methods of the base class, it is up to you.

Comment: I think you have not many solutions... if you can change the code use thr @IvanSmirnov solution with proxy class or you can return a raw pointer....